# File error by permistion in centos 7 magento 2?

Tags: magento2, centos

In Magento 2 I get an error in my VPS
 `... is not writable in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209`

i tried set
`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento` but not success. Any suggestion?

I checked permissions in my site.

folder 755
file   644
owner/group  nginx:nginx

in nginx.config
`user nginx;`
in php-fpm.config
`user: nginx
group: nginx`

somebody help me!

Comment: Try this way sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to var folder and pub/static folder and user of that folder must be apache
Check below command:

cd /var/www/html/magento2 && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R :apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento

Where /var/www/HTML/magento2 my magento directory.

Comment: yep, I set permission 777 to pub/static and var folder.

Comment: Have you checked above code?

Comment: is it set recursively like chmod -R 770 var app/etc pub/static? Also your php must have writable access to files. If you are using apache or php-fpm them make sure user www-data has permission to write in magento var directory. After you do this do ls -shalt and review permissions

Comment: @sunilpatel i were run this code. And I following http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: @xanda it is good article and I solved using that. Is that solved?

Comment: it not solved. Now i don't know where i need fix?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this.

1. Redhat based distros come with SELinux enabled. You have to either disable SELinux or update SELinux policies. Refer https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/security.html
2. Web server user should have enough permission to write files to the cache folder. If you are using PHP-FPM, PHP-FPM service user should have the permission. It might not be the same user as web server user.

Comment: i'm tried 1,2.  not success.  I'm use PHP-FPM and in config 

`listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx`

Comment: Try `sudo chown nginx:nginx -R .` under Magento document root.